# jupyter notebook export with embedded CSV files

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook

I need to share a jupyter notebook, a really simple interactive app using pandas, plotly and dash with some colleagues who have not installed Python.

If my notebook uses no csv files, it seems to work well.

But, is there any way to export in html format with somewhat embedded data in csv files?

Or any feasible workaround?

Thank you SO much!

Comment: I have an example [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/bouton-voila-sur-jupyterlite/18505/11?u=fomightez) where for a different reason, since addressed & fixed, I was encoding the content of the CSVs as strings within the notebook file. That example may help you? There's definitely other work arounds although I am not sure about Dash in this stack as it don't use it. And the big issue would be how private things need to be. But I'm not sure why you cannot make a JupyterHub and let your stakeholders connect and run? There's definitely way more options like ...

Comment: <continued> MyBinder, Voila, JupyterLite & Voici if privacy isn't a concern.